# How can I hide admin bar from my wordpress theme site while I'm logged in to customize it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress.
Need some help here,I want to remove wordpress admin bar from my website but not from admin panel to have a look for my website will look while I will publish.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

From your theme directory open function.php file and add the below code. Hope your problem will solve.

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it for all the users then paste this code into functions.php of your theme.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
     show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to hide it for all the users except admin,then you need to 
    add this code into funtions.php

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```